# Show nothing if the item doesn't have a date

Tags: date, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I want my code to display nothing if it doesn't have a date.

**Here is my code:**

```
=format(IIF(Fields!Phase.Value = "Pre-Feasibility" OR Fields!Phase.Value = "Selection", Fields!PreFeasibilityCurrentTargetDate.Value, IIF(Fields!Phase.Value = "Feasibility" OR Fields!Phase.Value = "Definition", Fields!FeasibilityCurrentTargetDate.Value, IIF(Fields!Phase.Value = "Implementation", Fields!ImplementationCurrentTargetDate.Value, ""))), "dd-MMM-yy")
```

Because I am formatting it to `dd-MMM-yy`, it displays that when the item doesn't have a date. How can i have this changed to display nothing if it doesn't have a date.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the blank values of your expression to nothing

```
=Iif(Fields!Phase.Value="Operation","-", format(
IIF(Fields!Phase.Value = "Pre-Feasibility" OR Fields!Phase.Value = "Selection", 
   Fields!PreFeasibilityCurrentTargetDate.Value, 
   IIF(Fields!Phase.Value = "Feasibility" OR Fields!Phase.Value = "Definition", 
      Fields!FeasibilityCurrentTargetDate.Value, 
      IIF(Fields!Phase.Value = "Implementation",
        Fields!ImplementationCurrentTargetDate.Value, Nothing)))
, "dd-MMM-yy") )
```

I would also advice you to use the field format property instead of the format function inside the value expression. In this case it works even if the field value is blank

Comment: I have updated my answer. You write an iif for this check and put all the rest expression on the else part.

Answer (score 0):

check the MSDN form here,
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157406.aspx

it clearly mention that "If you specify an invalid format string, the formatted text is interpreted as a literal string which overrides the formatting."

So. you need to check the string after formatting,

```
IIF(output="dd-MMM-yy","",output)
```